# useContext give error while accessing the values

Tags: react-hooks, react-context, createcontext

How can i fix it "useTheme is not a function or its return value is not iterable" while using create context and also i can't access values of createContext it gives error: "not define" while using those.

[my context provider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gxCv.png);

['app.js' cant access to the provider values.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzfjc.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26bI9.png)

[error: "useTheme is not a function or its return values is not iterable" while using UseTheme method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26bI9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that the context is an object and you destructure it using the { }
while in your code you used [ ]  [image: code]

Comment: ohh thanks soo much it tooks a lot of my time and didn't find it.